# GPIO pins mind bogling error

Tags: gpio, sensor, pi-3b+

[image]**Raspberry pi 3 b+**

I'm trying to make an Obstacle avoidance obstacles.

It's a very simple project. I tried with one ultra sonic sensor, it worked. Gave me the distance which i could further manipulate to avoid distance.

It wasn't very good, it collided a lot specially when it came at an angle to the wall or an object.

I then tried to mesh a network of Sensors (3 Ultra sonic sensor and 2 IR sensors) to work in combination for better obstacle avoidance. Seemed simple enough as well.

But I'm not able to run the other two ultra sonic sensors. Which is weird considering i set them up exactly the same.

I ran the same code just changing the GPIO pin number's that i have connected the ECHO and TRIG pin to.

the working pins were (GPIO.BOARD) 7, 11

I connected the TRIG and ECHO pins on 13,15 && 16,18

They don't seem to work. If i connect any sensors's pin to 7,11 they work. Other than these two pins I'm getting no response. I tried all 3 Sensors and the all work at 7,11 pins.

SO,

- The sensors work
- The connections are correct (VCC, GND)
- The code works

Need help. I have this feeling that the solution would be something very simple.

```
GPIO_TRIGGER = 7
GPIO_ECHO = 11
```

If i change them to

```
GPIO_TRIGGER = 13
GPIO_ECHO = 15
```

It doesnt work.. the same sensor that was working with the same code on 7,11

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

def distance():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

```
GPIO_TRIGGER = 13
GPIO_ECHO = 15


GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)

time.sleep(0.00001)

GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

starttime = time.time()
stoptime = time.time()

while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:
    starttime = time.time()

while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:
    stoptime = time.time()

timeElapsed = stoptime - starttime
distance = (timeElapsed * 34300)/2

return distance
try:
while True:
    far = distance()
    far = far - 1
    print('Distance = %.lf cm*' %far)

except:
KeyboardInterrupt
print('Stop sucessfull')
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: `The code works` how do you know? Does your code work work when you connect a single sensor to any of the alternative pin combinations? Maybe you can post (minimal) code that shows the problem.

Comment: My code works on the 7, 11 pins. If i connect any of the three sensors to these pins i get distance.

If i connect the same sensor to the other pins 13,15 OR 16,18. I don't get the Distance from the Sensor.

I was just testing initially whether all the sensors work or not

Comment: Yes, but you cannot say your code works until you can make one or more sensors working on the other pins.

Comment: The two lines you posted just now don't add any info. What if the code uses fixed values somewhere else?

Comment: The code as posted will never work. Too many problems with it. I can see indentation problems and the `except` statement will also raise an error. You also should not put setup statements inside a function that is called many times (first 5 lines of `distance`). Using the same name for a function and a variable could also cause problems. I suggest you clean up your code first and then try again.

Comment: That is definitely good advice. I will follow it to make my code better. But as i already said the code works, distance is being printed when i connect any of the three sensors echo and trig pins on 7,11 Board pins. I know it works because i can see the distance being printed on the terminal. It changes with the actual distance  of the obstacle in front of it

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your circuit diagram? Which sensor are you using? If it is the HC-SR04, the echo pin is rated at 5V and you will need a voltage divider. Not mentioned in your description if you used the divider. The Raspberry Pi GPIO pins are not 5V tolerant and can be damaged. See: https://www.modmypi.com/blog/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi.

**Edit to Add: Most likely the problem is due to the fact that the voltage divider as you have it right now is only putting out 1.67 V which is less than the 2V needed.**

Comment: I used the above mentioned schematic. I used the voltage divider to make the voltage 3.3 v

Comment: Thanks.  Wonder if the Pi is faulty. Do you have a DVM? Maybe you can check the voltages.

Comment: Just noticed that divider is incorrect assuming all resistors are the same.

Comment: Yes i was thinking the same thing. Maybe the PI is faulty. Unfortunately i don't have a DVM handy at the moment. It's just wired and makes no sense, a simple code should work and i just change the pin numbers and connect the sensors pin to them. changing nothing else.

Comment: Oh. that can be the case. I'll check them too

Comment: Remove the short. Instead move the first resistor that goes to ground to that place. You should have 2R/3R.

Comment: right now its R/2R . which gives us 2.5 V. Shouldn't that be okay for the application?

Comment: Right now it is R/3R.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that the voltage high threshold was around 2V.

Comment: The resistors below the voltage divider are 20k ohms. The resistor above is 10k ohms. By that logic It's 2/3 * 5V = 3.3V. With the same configuration the same code is working on the pins 7 and 11. Unless there is a minimum Current threshold as well, i dont see the logic why it works on the 7 and 11 pins and not on any other pins

Comment: R1 = 10k and R2 = 10+10 k . Voltage is taken across R2. therefore it's 20k/30k .. 2/3 *5V = 3.3V

Comment: The way you have it connected, R2 has two 10K resistors in parallel. So equal to 5K.